# build google/gxui samples error on mac

Tags: go, glfw, gxui, go-gl

I git clone code from github.com/google/gxui
and then

> cd samples/hello_word
>
> GOOS=windows go build

an error  occurred
it says

> /d01/gopath/src/github.com/goxjs/gl/gl_opengl.go:10:2: no buildable Go
> source files in /d01/gopath/src/github.com/go-gl/gl/v2.1/gl
> /d01/gopath/src/github.com/goxjs/glfw/desktop.go:10:2: no buildable Go
> source files in /d01/gopath/src/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.2/glfw

I try to

> go get -u github.com/go-gl/gl/v2.1/gl go get -u
> github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.2/glfw

no error  occurred

I try to run again

> GOOS=windows go build

The problem has not been solved

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because of your mac doesn't have a c compiler that can cross compiler to the target OS. I tried it on a Linux OS and it compiles without any issues. there was an issue on git about it [last year](https://github.com/goxjs/gl/issues/22) and it's still open till today. I would suggest compiling it directly on the target OS. If you look throught the code in

```
github.com/go-gl/gl/v2.1/gl/conversions.go
```

you will notice that it import "c" meaing it will require a C compiler that is compartible with the target OS.